Given a (nice) family of PDFs and a (nice) family of values, is there a (nice) random variable with those expectations?
Nice here is to be taken as smooth/continuous/differentiable/whatever. I'm going to just write out the integral here as I'm not as comfortable with EV notation.
Say I have a (nice) function $p: M \times C \to \mathbb{R}$ such that each member of the family $(p(m))_{c \in C}$ is a probability density function. Further, I have a (nice) function $r: C \to \mathbb{R}$. Is there a (nice) function $q: M \times C \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $c \in C$, $\displaystyle \int_{m\in M} p(m,c)dm = r(c)$?
Feel free to add additional assumptions. This problem is motivated by industry work, but I feel like this has to have been studied somewhere in the literature. My pre-industry work in model theory isn't a big help :)

$q$ does not appear in the main equation anywhere.
